# How do I get all the items which have same String key android firebase

Tags: android, firebase

[I want to get all the items which have same league id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzJo2.jpg)

I want to get all the items which have same league id within the teams node and in that node I have push key and then an object, with Firebase query , If any one knows about it please help.  Link to Image ->  https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzJo2.jpg
and result is > System.out: LOG DataSnapshot { key = teams, value = null }

```
val query = databaseRef.child("teams").orderByChild("leagueId").equalTo("LS9t7MgdIuHrDP0vEME")
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
                override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                    println("LOG $dataSnapshot")

                }

                override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {

                }
            })
```

Comment: Only within `teams` node?

Comment: yes in the team node I have pushId, and in that pushId I have a object, I am trying to upload snapshot of it but I can't

Comment: and in that object I have a value like this (leagueId:value)

Comment: This is easily found in firebase docs. Just search for queries. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries

Comment: I have already searched alot that's why I m here @newbieCoder.pkg  :(

Comment: Please add some code of the problem you are struggling with so we can help. Not providing specific details can result in your question get down voted. Speaking from experience. Cheers

Comment: I have tried to add snapshot but its not showing here.@TheeBen

Comment: @TheeBen I have attached a link of the scenerio in the question please check it,

Comment: @TheeBen I have tried this code ,                                                                                           val query = databaseRef.child("teams").orderByChild("leagueId").equalTo("LS9t7MgdIuHrDP0vEME")
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                println("LOG $dataSnapshot")
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
            }
        })

Comment: @KamranAli , please add your trials to the question. Better that way, everyone sees it, and also what do you see when you try that?

Comment: When I am trying my code it give me this in log ,    "LOG DataSnapshot { key = teams, value = null }"

Comment: It is working if my nested value is Integer but its not working when it is String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the items within the `teams` node that correspond to a specific id, please use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("teams").orderByChild("leagueId").equalsTo(desiredId);
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String team = ds.child("team").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, team);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

In which the `desiredId` should hold a value as `-LS9t ... vEME`. The output in your logcat will be, the name of all teams that have the id equal to `-LS9t ... vEME`.

Comment: Why do you say it is not working. Do you have an error or what? Have you also tried to use a hardcoded id?

Comment: yes I have tried with the hardCoded id also, and in log its showing me this result,  LOG DataSnapshot { key = teams, value = null }

Comment: Edit your question and add the exact code that you are using. There is certainly a place where something is wrong.

Comment: This case is working when my nested value is in Integer form, but not working when I change it to String.

Comment: Should also work in String format. Please add the code that you are using.

Comment: Change `LS9t7MgdIuHrDP0vEME` with `-LS9t7MgdIuHrDP0vEME`. See, there is a minus in front. Does it work now?

Comment: Thanks Alot  man its working, You just saved my headache... I am strugging with this issue from last 2 hours.